# TensorFlow pip install not working on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I have spent a lot of time tying to install tensorflow for windows. I keep getting errors like "not supported."

I have tried the commands:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

and

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Can you paste the error messages.?

Comment: You need Python 3.6, which can be installed from here https://python.org/download. Nothing else will work with tensorflow on Windows.

Comment: I do have Python 3.6 and the error message I get is: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow"

Answer (score 1):

I found that tensorflow works with python 3.7-3.10 so if you have a higher version of python, consider installing an older one.
It worked for me, I had python 3.11 is I installed python 3.9 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Note that TensorFlow needs x64 Windows and that Python 3.5 and higher go with `pip3` instead of `pip`. Still, there's a glitch with the installation script; I ran into the same problem and resolved it by using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section), an alternative package manager for R and Python.

Once you've installed Anaconda, run the Anaconda prompt, create a new environment (called here `tfenv`), and activate it:

```
>conda create -n tfenv
>conda activate tfenv
```

Then, you can install TensorFlow

```
>conda install tensorflow
```

Answer (score -1):

to install tensor flow you need to do this:

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

it seems to work, and has a different link to yours. I think your link may be for a different system.